# Combining rows in T-SQL using STUFF or CONCAT command

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am looking at modifying the following query in a program (this was written before my time here as Software Engineer so please bear with me...):

```
SELECT
        Participant.ParticipantID            AS "ParticipantId",
        Stream.StreamName                    AS "StreamName",
        ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime    AS "ConnectTime",
        ParticipantStatistics.DisconnectTime AS "DisconnectTime",
        FormField.FieldLabel                 AS "FieldLabel",
        RegistrantAnswer.Answer              AS "Answer"
    FROM   ParticipantStatistics
        INNER JOIN Participant ON ParticipantStatistics.ParticipantId = Participant.ParticipantID
        INNER JOIN Registrant ON Registrant.RegistrantId = Participant.RegistrantID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RegistrantAnswer ON RegistrantAnswer.RegistrantID = Registrant.RegistrantID
        INNER JOIN Event ON Event.EventId = Participant.EventID
        INNER JOIN Stream ON Stream.MediaEventId = Event.EventId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FormField ON RegistrantAnswer.FormFieldId = FormField.FormFieldId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ParticipantID, SurveyID FROM ParticipantSurvey) 
        AS SurveyCompleted ON SurveyCompleted.ParticipantID = Participant.ParticipantID
    WHERE  Stream.StreamId = '2235'
        AND Participant.Visible = 1
        ORDER  BY Participant.ParticipantID, OrderNumber, ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime ASC
```

This query gives me the following information:

[image]

What I would like to do is modify the above query to return the results as one row as follows:

```
| 315314 | ffbc110729 | 2011-10-27 03:13:06.240 | 2011-10-27 03:17:12.473 | **First Name, Last Name, Email, Company** | **ads, asd, asd@asd.com, asdf** |
```

Where the last two columns are combined, separated by commas in a single row.

Is this possible using either `STUFF` or `CONCAT`?  I am new to T-SQL so please let me know if you need further clarification.

Best Regards,

**EDIT:** When I try to edit with `STUFF FOR XML PATH` I set it up the following way:

```
    SELECT 
        Participant.ParticipantID            AS "ParticipantId",
        Stream.StreamName                    AS "StreamName",
        ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime    AS "ConnectTime",
        ParticipantStatistics.DisconnectTime AS "DisconnectTime",
    STUFF ((SELECT ','+ FormField.FieldLabel FROM FormField WHERE FormField.FormFieldID = RegistrantAnswer.FormFieldID FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
    FROM   ParticipantStatistics
        INNER JOIN Participant ON ParticipantStatistics.ParticipantId = Participant.ParticipantID
        INNER JOIN Registrant ON Registrant.RegistrantId = Participant.RegistrantID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RegistrantAnswer ON RegistrantAnswer.RegistrantID = Registrant.RegistrantID
        INNER JOIN Event ON Event.EventId = Participant.EventID
        INNER JOIN Stream ON Stream.MediaEventId = Event.EventId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FormField ON RegistrantAnswer.FormFieldId = FormField.FormFieldId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ParticipantID, SurveyID FROM ParticipantSurvey) 
        AS SurveyCompleted ON SurveyCompleted.ParticipantID = Participant.ParticipantID
    WHERE  Stream.StreamId = '2235'
        AND Participant.Visible = 1
        ORDER  BY Participant.ParticipantID, OrderNumber, ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime ASC
```

I then receive the following:

[image]

Again, I am fairly new to T-SQL so maybe I am setting it up wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to look at STUFF FOR XML PATH('').

Comment: Thank you.  I have been looking at various examples using this method.  I have been attempting to get things working but I cannot figure out how to get this specific query to run by doing so.

Comment: Well, for example, in your SELECT statement, rather than selecting the fieldlabel, you want to select `STUFF((SELECT ','+fieldlabel FROM formfield WHERE formfieldid = registrantanswer.formfieldid FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')` and you could probably rearrange your query to not require as many joins as it's currently doing as well.

Comment: What happened when you attempted to use STUFF FOR XML PATH with this query?   Did you get an error?  What was the error?   Post your attempt so that we can debug it.

Comment: I posted an edit above.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't post images of your sample data or results. It's very rude here, and it makes it harder for us to help you because we have to re-type things in order to set up tests for our solutions.

Comment: As people have commented on before: For questions like these you should provide some sample data in script form so that people don't have to type this all out to provide an answer. One way to provide this is described [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), using [ConvertCSV](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm).

Comment: My apologies, I did not know that was unacceptable.  I can see now why it would be annoying though.  Dually noted for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Participant.ParticipantID            AS "ParticipantId",
    Stream.StreamName                    AS "StreamName",
    ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime    AS "ConnectTime",
    ParticipantStatistics.DisconnectTime AS "DisconnectTime",
    STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + FormField.FieldLabel as'text()'
       FROM Registrant
          LEFT OUTER JOIN RegistrantAnswer ON RegistrantAnswer.RegistrantID = Registrant.RegistrantID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN FormField ON RegistrantAnswer.FormFieldId = FormField.FormFieldId
       WHERE Registrant.RegistrantId = Participant.RegistrantID
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 2, '') AS "FieldLabel",
    STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + RegistrantAnswer.Answer as'text()'
       FROM Registrant
          LEFT OUTER JOIN RegistrantAnswer ON RegistrantAnswer.RegistrantID = Registrant.RegistrantID 
       WHERE Registrant.RegistrantId = Participant.RegistrantID
       FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 2, '') AS "Answer"
FROM   ParticipantStatistics
    INNER JOIN Participant ON ParticipantStatistics.ParticipantId = Participant.ParticipantID
    INNER JOIN Registrant ON Registrant.RegistrantId = Participant.RegistrantID
    INNER JOIN Event ON Event.EventId = Participant.EventID
    INNER JOIN Stream ON Stream.MediaEventId = Event.EventId
WHERE  Stream.StreamId = '2235'
    AND Participant.Visible = 1
ORDER  BY Participant.ParticipantID, OrderNumber, ParticipantStatistics.ConnectTime ASC
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly for me!  Thank you very much for your help it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This returns the data exactly how I want, hence the reason for accepting your answer.  Thanks again by the way.  However there is one caveat.  I am using MyBatis to execute the query which returns the results to me in Java.  I am using a resultMap to return my data so I changed "FieldLabel" to "FormField_FieldLabel" and "Answer" to "RegistrantAnswer_Answer" to match my resultMap setup.  When I call the query, all of the data gets passed back except for the two columns that I mention above.  Does the STUFF command not work with MyBatis?

Comment: My apologies, we are using iBATIS, not MyBatis.  Apparently it didn't like the commas for some reason.  I replaced the commas with tildes and it is working fine now.  I thought I would let you know in case this comment may help someone out in the future.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using `STUFF` + `FOR XML PATH('')` is usually the most practical in SQL Server to concatenate strings. This sample first populates the resultset in an intermediary temporary table for the sake of keeping things readable and manageable.

```
SELECT *
INTO #fiddle_table
FROM (
        VALUES
            (315314,'ffbc110729',{ts '2011-10-27 03:13:06.240'},{ts '2011-10-27 03:17:12.473'},'First Name','ads'),
            (315314,'ffbc110729',{ts '2011-10-27 03:13:06.240'},{ts '2011-10-27 03:17:12.473'},'Last Name','asd'),
            (315314,'ffbc110729',{ts '2011-10-27 03:13:06.240'},{ts '2011-10-27 03:17:12.473'},'Email','asd@asd.com'),
            (315314,'ffbc110729',{ts '2011-10-27 03:13:06.240'},{ts '2011-10-27 03:17:12.473'},'Company','asdf')
     ) AS v(participantid,streamname,connecttime,disconnecttime,fieldlabel,answer);

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        participantid,streamname,connecttime,disconnecttime
    FROM
        #fiddle_table
)
SELECT
    participantid,streamname,connecttime,disconnecttime,
    fieldlabels=STUFF((
        SELECT ', '+fieldlabel
        FROM #fiddle_table AS i
        WHERE i.participantid=o.participantid
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,''
    ),
    answers=STUFF((
        SELECT ', '+answer
        FROM #fiddle_table AS i
        WHERE i.participantid=o.participantid
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
FROM cte AS o;

DROP TABLE #fiddle_table;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| participantid | streamname |       connecttime       |     disconnecttime      |              fieldlabels              |           answers           |
+---------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|        315314 | ffbc110729 | 2011-10-27 03:13:06.240 | 2011-10-27 03:17:12.473 | First Name, Last Name, Email, Company | ads, asd, asd@asd.com, asdf |
+---------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: I like the way that you accomplished this using temp tables.  Very intuitive.  Thank you very much for your help!